# Getting CloudDriveException: ERROR_HTTPS_NOT_SUPPORTED in the Windows Azure environment

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I've set the DefaultEndpointsProtocol to "http" in the service configuration file, but still I get the ERROR_HTTPS_NOT_SUPPORTED exception during the cloud drive creation. Is there anything else that I need to look for?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud drive can currently use only HTTP storage connection string:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.clouddrive.delete.aspx

"When defining the connection string for connecting to the storage account, you must use the HTTP protocol. The HTTPS protocol is not supported for creating a drive."

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/farida/archive/2012/04/23/cloud-drive-can-currently-use-only-http-storage-connection-string.aspx